# Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In Sakurai, 
it is stated that,

> the coefficients (Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients) vanish unless
>   $|j_1 − j_2| \le j \le j_1 + j_2$.

In the book it is just given that the relation is satified. But I am asking for a formal proof regarding this.

Ref - Modern Quantum Mechanics-2nd ed (Sakurai) (eqn no. - 8.38)

Comment: ${128^128}^128$

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91100/triangle-inequality-clebsch-gordan-coeffcients?rq=1)